# Is it possible to change size of section with animation in IGListSectionController?

Tags: ios, swift, iglistkit

Is it possible to change size of section with animation in IGListSectionController? Or trigger recalculation of `sizeForItem`?

I have expandable label in section, that is when tap happened new view displayed with animation. But height of the section was not recalculated, so new view pushed out all other views out of the bottom bound of the section. And they are not visible anymore. I want to extend section height in order to show all views in section.

[image: Exampele of section.]

Size of section is provided with:

```
func sizeForItem(at index: Int) -> CGSize
{
    let height: CGFloat = self.expanded ? 200 + 300 : 200
    return CGSize(width: collectionContext!.containerSize.width, height: height)
}
```

And `expanded` property set to true upon tap.